FullCalendar with Fiscal Calendar
I'm using FullCalendar for React. Instead of a regular calendar year, I would like to use a fiscal calendar. For instance, the current fiscal year (FY25) should begin on Sep 29, 2024 and end on Sep 27, 2025. The fiscal month of October should display 9/29 through 11/2. The current fiscal week should be 5.
Is there a way to change the underlying calendar object in this way?
I have read the responses to How to set full calendar to a specific start date when it's initialized for the 1st time? and they do not answer my question. That question is regarding setting the initial, default date when the calendar is initialized. The question I have is how to redefine the calendar itself. How to redefine a year. In a fiscal year, the start and end date are different from the calendar year. The start and end date of each month is different. The numbers of the weeks are different.

This question is similar to: How to set full calendar to a specific start date when it's initialized for the 1st time?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

For the "month" view no I don't think you can do this - it's pretty rigid. For the other view types I expect you can do some calculations in a visibleRange callback to make it set the relevant ranges.

If you want support for this built-in to a future fullCalendar release, take a look at https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features . Remember that not everyone's fiscal year is the same as yours.
